# Upgrading from Tomcat 5.5 to Tomcat 7

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, tomcat7

I do not post that many questions here and I am sorry if I am asking wrong but I am currently trying to update this web application that I work on to use Tomcat7. I have ran into alot of bumps along the road and I have corrected them but this one I cannot seem to figure out. Right now I am at the point where Tomcat starts and I can launch the web application page, but when I log into the web application i get a "Problem with server" error message. THen i Have the following error message in the tomcat logs

> 

```
21 Aug 2014 14:56:57 ERROR ajp-bio-8009-exec-1 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/infoAgentSrv].[iFixWeb] - Servlet.service() for servlet [iFixWeb] in context with path [/infoAgentSrv] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: stub class initialization failed
    at com.gefanuc.proficyrtip.server.iFixWeb_Stub.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.Util.createStub(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.Util.createProxy(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.gefanuc.proficyrtip.server.iFixWeb.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.gefanuc.proficyrtip.server.Session.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.gefanuc.proficyrtip.server.iFixWebServlet.doGet(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:190)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
21 Aug 2014 14:56:57 ERROR ajp-bio-8009-exec-1 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/infoAgentSrv].[iFixWeb] - Servlet.service() for servlet [iFixWeb] in context with path [/infoAgentSrv] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.gefanuc.proficyrtip.server.iFixWeb_Stub
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.Util.createStub(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.Util.createProxy(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.gefanuc.proficyrtip.server.iFixWeb.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.gefanuc.proficyrtip.server.Session.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.gefanuc.proficyrtip.server.iFixWebServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:190)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
21 Aug 2014 14:57:04 ERROR ajp-bio-8009-exec-1 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/infoAgentSrv].[iFixWeb] - Servlet.service() for servlet [iFixWeb] in context with path [/infoAgentSrv] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.gefanuc.proficyrtip.server.iFixWeb_Stub
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.Util.createStub(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.Util.createProxy(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.gefanuc.proficyrtip.server.iFixWeb.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.gefanuc.proficyrtip.server.Session.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.gefanuc.proficyrtip.server.iFixWebServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:190)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any idea what could cause this? I understand the basics...for some reason the stub class is not being created in the RMI registry ( I might be wrong ). What changes in tomcat7 could cause this? Any help would be greatly appreciated and I am apologize if I did a bad job at asking this question.

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.gefanuc.proficyrtip.server.iFixWeb_Stub` means the class is missing from the _runtime_ classpath.

Comment: @JimGarrison Sorry if this is a silly question, but by runtime classpath do you mean the class path that tomcat runs off of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, class com.gefanuc.proficyrtip.server.iFixWeb_Stub is missing.

That class is not related to Tomcat (nor included), so a JAR must be missing from your current classpath.

Comment: Turns out I was missing a .jar under my WEB-INF/LIB folder, I also had to tweak my server.xml and context.xml to use some older attributes that were turned off by default in tomcat 7